# Как прибавить соседние цифры в числе?

Tags: python

например число 1234
вот как код должен работать
результат: 3 5 7
думаю вы поняли
Я уже знаю один способ, но хотела бы узнать другие способы, заранее спасибо вам!

Вот мой способ:

```
number_list = []
user_number = input()
for index in user_number:
    number_list.append(index)

n = -1

for i in range(len(number_list) -  1):
    n += 1
    print(int(number_list[n]) + int(number_list[n+1]))
```

Answer (score 3):

можно сделать так:

```
def f(num):
    num = str(num)
    return [int(a) + int(b) for a, b in zip(num, num[1:])]

print(f(1234))
```

---

В вашем коде

```
user_number = input()
for index in user_number:
    number_list.append(index)
```

можно заменить на

```
user_number = input()
number_list = list(user_number)
```

также от `n` можно избавиться и использовать `i`

```
for i in range(len(number_list) -  1):
    print(int(number_list[i]) + int(number_list[i+1]))
```

Comment: как дополнение к вашему 1-му варианту:`return [sum(map(int, pair)) for pair in zip(num, num[1:])]`